# Display images Horizontally or vertically in a Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do is to flip the images depending if their `Heigh` is higher than they `Width`, or them `Width` is bigger than their `Height`.

If The Hight is Higher: Display the image Vertically
If the Width is Higher: Display the image Horizontally.

Here I can show yo how the images are displaying now..

This image has to be Horizontal

[image]

This image is Vertically (Ok)

[image]

This was what I was trying but with not luck. I know I have to change `modal-dialog`, but I'm unable to do it.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let modalImg = document.getElementById('modal-dialog');

    for (var i = 0; i < modalImg.lenght; i++) {
        if (modalImg[i].naturalWidth > modalImg[i].naturalHeight) {
            modalImg[i].style.maxWidth = '50vw';
        } else {
            modalImg[i].style.maxWidth = '30vw';
            modalImg[i].style.maxHeight = '80vh';
        }
    }
});
```

The gallery is loaded dinamically, all images are brought from the BD.

```js
function GetImagenes2(img) {    
    let imgId = img.id;
    let body = document.getElementById('bodyId');
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    let imageShow = document.getElementById("carousel-item_" + imgId)


    if (img.naturalWidth > img.naturalHeight) {
        img.style.maxWidth = '50vw';
    } else {
        img.style.maxWidth = '30vw';
        img.style.maxHeight = '80vh';
    }

    imageShow.className += " active";
    body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
    .modal {
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 0 !important;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-top: 2%;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
        text-align: center;

        .modal-dialog {
            .modal-content {
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;


                .modal-body .carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item .img-responsive {
                    height: 70vh;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }

            .carusel {
                .carousel-control-prev {
                    margin-left: 15%;

                    #SpanArrowLeft {
                        font-size: 50px;
                    }
                }

                .carousel-control-next {
                    margin-right: 15%;

                    #SpanArrowRight {
                        font-size: 50px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div id="myModal" class="modal" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseModal()" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="C_@item.getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/14/13/23/ocean-3605547_640.jpg" class="d-block w-100"  alt="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/28/10/36/road-220058_640.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/23/07/35/thunderstorm-3625405_640.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
              </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carusel">
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" id="btnPrev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@item.getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="prev">
                          <span class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left" id="SpanArrowLeft" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" id="btnNext" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@item.getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right" id="SpanArrowRight" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>


<img class="imgPedido" id="@cont" src="@pd.getImagenes()" onclick="GetImagenes2(this)" data-img-mostrar="@cont" />
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.
Please do NOT post server code when your issue is client rendering

Comment: Flipping images (not related to EXIF) is a silly idea.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan So, what do you recommend?

Comment: To simply not rotate them. Eventually you can add a library that can zoom an pan your image - if that's needed.

Comment: But I'm not trying to zoom..